# How do you say "to network" in French?

Tags: expressions

How do you say "to network" as in going to an event that people attend with the goal of making professional contacts?  Is there a parallel French phrase that is used?

Answer (score 8):

We used to call it *relations*, hence the expression:

> *Se faire des relations* (also: *se faire des contacts*)

Nowadays, there is also *réseau* which matches the English "network" <s>but like *relation* has no verbal form,</s> so we say:

> *Se faire un réseau*

or

> *Travailler/entretenir son réseau*

As a couple of comments stated, there is an emerging verbal form: *réseauter*.

It's usage might still be frowned upon but is steadily rising anyway:

[image]

Comment: There is a verbal form, although I expect some people may frown about it: *réseauter*.

Comment: on peut aussi dire *se faire des contacts*

Comment: [*réseauter*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/r%C3%A9seauter/186714) is being used increasingly

Comment: @Greg Je l'avais écarté comme incorrect mais il est plus répandu que je ne le soupçonnais. Merci !

Comment: This sounds too similar to réussir to me and could be confused L/

Comment: @cloud correctly pronounced "réseauter" doesn’t sound anything like "réussir". I don’t know how to write phonetics, but appart from "ré" there’s no common sound in those two verbs...

Comment: @cloud, /ʀeysiʀ/ and /ʀezote/ sound nothing alike.

*Réseautage* is also worth mentioning as the neological translation of *networking*

Comment: Bonne question et bonne réponse. Je n'ai pas connu le verb résauter. Le dictionnaire Livio (Android) en parle en précisant qu'il s'agit d'un néologisme. Moi, je le trouve plus françisé que   networker. Mais, je me demande quelle l'opponion de l'académie francaise☺.

Comment: Il fallait que j'écrive <<...quelle est l'opinion...>>. Je m'excuse.

Comment: L'Académie française ne s'est sûrement pas encore prononcée sur *réseauter* mais elle a entériné *poireauter* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Network in English literally mean Réseau in French.

I would probably say « Se faire un réseau »

Answer (score 1):

Se brancher ou se bâtir sa communauté, son réseau.